# json_encode crashes because of a character

Tags: php, json, character-encoding

I have an array of arrays. Each inner array has string elements.

One of the strings contain: –

This causes

> Exception 'PHPErrorException' with message '**Warning** [2]
>   json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument

when I call `json_encode`. If the character is not present, the function call works. How could I make sure that any characters are supported by `json_encode`, or not supported characters are ignored? I have been playing around with `iconv` and all kinds of conversion but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried iterating your array and running `htmlentities` on each string within before passing to `json_encode`?

If the problem is with the dash then html encoding it may help (although there are several different types of dash, so would help to know which dash specifically PHP is falling over on).

As pointed out below, may need `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` (PHP 5.4+)

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: `json_encode(htmlentities($source));`

If that doesn't work, can you post a sample of the JSON you're getting errors with.

Comment: json_encode(htmlentities($source)) will not work on an array of arrays as specified in the question. We have to do that for each string inside the array of arrays.

Comment: I have specified the character I have problems with. Try with array(0 => array(0 => "–")); No need for the exact example. The problem is that some characters are not supported. We should not lose ourselves in the details.

Comment: Well we'll need some details.... how are you running json_encode? Are you looping your array of arrays? And are you certain the dash character your PHP is failing on is the same dash character you've typed above? Without an exact example I don't know where your code is failing!

Comment: Trust me, you will not happy to see a long parsing code. Please, read the question, every detail you need is specified there. Array of arrays. Each inner array has strings inside. One of the strings contain the character specified in the question. Warning is thrown. This is the issue. I did not give code with a purpose. We should solve the essence of the problem, not tackle with example codes. I would like to know what is the problem not to see a solution.

Comment: There is a hyphen minus, so htmlentities might be the solution, but if I iterate my array and use it, it works on my local server, but throws the same warning on live server. Something with the settings might also affect the issue. An answer about what should be looked at and what could cause this issue would be more than  enough. This is not a "what should I do" question. It is a "why could this happen" kind of question. It is about understanding, not about code.

Comment: ENT_SUBSTITUTE is not supported in < PHP 5.4. The live server users older PHP.

Comment: Can you add some information from this chat to your answer? The issue has an answer and I would like to accept yours instead of writing my own, because you gave your two cents to solve the problem.

Comment: Expanded the answer a bit, but not sure what else you want added to it? Are you saying that the lack of ENT_SUBSTITUTE in PHP 5.4 caused your problem?

Comment: That is what I am talking about. Answer accepted and upvoted. Note, that the htmlentities needs the ENT_SUBSTITUTE flag to properly work and PHP of version 5.4. at least is needed for it to work. I am fighting now to upgrade the life server's PHP. This might also be an important detail to add to the answer. Nevertheless, the answer is almost perfect the way it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `en dash`. Please look [here.](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Why don't you try [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) using this character `–` and its corresponding HTML Number `&#8211;`